# How can I save these values to my db by using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I am using AWS Lambda and struggling at saving data to my database. Actually, I completed to saved datas in my db with few values.

like this.

```
const insertData = () => {
    const data = { gender: 'male', age: 360, money: '2100'};
    const { gender, age, money } = data;
    const query = 'INSERT INTO form_results (user_gender, user_age, user_transaction, ) VALUES (?, ?, ?)';
    const values = [gender, age, money];
```

And then I can check the data's values at my database by using DBeaver.
Now I want to get datas not directly like that, parsing value at json.
So I changed my codes like this.

```
const insertData = (eventData) => {
      const { gender, age, money} = eventData;
      const query = 'INSERT INTO form_results (user_gender, user_age, user_transaction) VALUES (?, ?, ?)';
      const values = [gender, age, money];

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connection.query(query, values, (error, results, fields) => {
          if (error) {
            console.error('Data insert error: ' + error);
            reject(error);
          } else {
            console.log('Data insert success');
            console.log(eventData);
            resolve();
          }
        });
      });
    };

try {
      await connectToDatabase();
      await insertData(eventData);
      connection.end();
      return {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Data insert success' })
      };
    } catch (error) {
      connection.end();
      return {
        statusCode: 500,
        body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Data insert failed' })
      };
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      statusCode: 400,
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Wrong event' })
    };
  }
```

Then I Run the code and it responds the status 400, Wrong event.
There's no error code and I don't know what's the problem.

Comment: do `JSON.stringify({ message: 'Wrong event', error:error })` so you at least *know*  what error was raised. Or add logging in that catch block. `console.log(error);` should tell you more.